# Play playlist from default android player (from code)

Tags: android, media-player

I am trying from my android code to play a specific playlist by playlist id from the default android media player. but my code doesnt seem to work. Thank you all.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName ("com.android.music","com.android.music.PlaylistBrowserActivity")); 
    intent.setType(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.CONTENT_TYPE); 
    intent.setFlags(0x10000000); 
    intent.putExtra("oneshot", false); 
    intent.putExtra("playlist", playListId); 
    context.startActivity(intent);
```

I added this to the Manifest : `<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me : it may help you

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
Uri data = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/myVideo.avi");
intent.setDataAndType(data, "video/avi");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Thank you. I want to play a playlist and not a video :(